# Browse JMS Messages in JBoss AS 7 / WildFly

Tags: jboss, wildfly

I'd like to know if it's possible to browse the JMS messages which have been sent (but not delivered) using the CLI (or any other management tool).
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually that's not possible. You can browse the list of messages in various format (HTML/JSON) but you can't browse for the message content using the default management tool. Consider using a tool like [HermesJMS](http://www.hermesjms.com/confluence/display/HJMS/Home) if you want to browse your message content or simply write by yourself a [Message Browser](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1841/bncey/index.html)